# ¿Cómo puedo insertar un mailto en php?

Tags: php, html

Lo que intento hacer es insertar la instrucción:

```
<a href="mailto:cuenta@deemail.com">
```

A un ciclo `while` que extrae los usuarios, correos y nivel educativo de una base de datos, y los presenta en una tabla, pero no acepta la instrucción y me marca un error.

Mi codigo:

```
while($reg=$resultado->fetch_array())
{
 echo"<table p align=center width=577 border=1>
  <tr>
    <td>".$reg['Usuario']."</td>
    <td><a href="mailto:$reg['Correo']">".$reg['Correo']."</td>
    <td>".$reg['Nivel']."</td>
  </tr> ";
 echo"</table>";
}
```

Linea en la que me marca el error:

```
<td><a href="mailto:$reg['Correo']">".$reg['Correo']."</td>
```

Comment: No estás poniendo bien las comillas. Si empiezas el `echo` con comillas dobles, no puedes  tener un atributo html con comillas dobles, debes usar comillas simples o escapar las comillas dobles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No estás poniendo bien las comillas. Si empiezas el `echo` con comillas dobles, no puedes  tener un atributo html con comillas dobles porque se romperá la cadena. Debes usar comillas simples o escapar las comillas dobles.

Como estás usando comillas dobles, las variables se analizarán y se cambiarán por su valor por lo que no necesitas estar haciendo concatenaciones con `.` que pueden añadir más complejidad (puedes leer más sobre esto en la [documentación de PHP sobre cadenas de caracteres](http://php.net/manual/es/language.types.string.php)), lo único es que al trabajar con arrays e índices, para evitar problemas, deberías envolver las variables con `{` y `}`.

Además, te faltaría cerrar el `<a>` o podrías tener problemas:

```
while($reg=$resultado->fetch_array())
{
 echo"<table p align=center width=577 border=1>
  <tr>
    <td>".$reg['Usuario']."</td>
    <td><a href='mailto:{$reg['Correo']}'>{$reg['Correo']}</a></td>
    <td>".$reg['Nivel']."</td>
  </tr> ";
 echo"</table>";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Es de esta manera:

```
 while($reg=$resultado->fetch_array())
{
 echo"<table p align=center width=577 border=1>
  <tr>
    <td>".$reg['Usuario']."</td>
    <td><a href=\"mailto:".$reg['Correo']."\">".$reg['Correo']."</a></td>
    <td>".$reg['Nivel']."</td>
  </tr> ";
 echo"</table>";
}
```

Tu problema estaba en las comillas dobles, y que no estabas concatenando la variable $reg['Correo']